# Handling the screen orientation change in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a Component whose content changes when the screen orientation(portrait/landscape) changes. This is what I am doing:

```
 var Greeting = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {orientation: true}
    },
    handleChange: function() {
        if ('onorientationchange' in window) {
            window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
                this.setState({
                    orientation: !this.state.orientation
                })
                console.log("onorientationchange");
            }, false);
        } else if ('onresize' in window) {
            window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
                this.setState({
                    orientation: !this.state.orientation
                })
                console.log("resize");
            }, false);
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        var message = this.state.orientation ? "Hello" : "Good bye"
        return <p>{message}</p>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Greeting/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

How to make sure the state is mutated when the orientation change event is fired .

Comment: what's the problem exactly? You don't know how to call handleChange when orientation changes? Or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your calling to `this.setState` is wrong. Need to change it to be like:

```
handleChange: function() {
    var self = this;          // Store `this` component outside the callback
    if ('onorientationchange' in window) {
        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
            // `this` is now pointing to `window`, not the component. So use `self`.
            self.setState({   
                orientation: !self.state.orientation
            })
            console.log("onorientationchange");
        }, false);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Where should I call this.handleChange?

Comment: You can call it when the component is mounted: [`componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount).

Comment: This causes a memory leak.  You should use the fat arrow on your callbacks or bind this to the function somehow.

Comment: orientationchange support is dropped now.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event